# Missing JBoss Server Runtime Library in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, runtime, classpath

How to add JBoss or JBoss EAP library to the Java Build Path of my project in Eclipse?

My platform:
Virtual machine with Windows XP sp3, JDK 7 and JRE 7, Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers
(Version: Kepler Service Release 2), new clean workspace in Eclipse

What I did:

1. Installed JBoss Tools for Kepler from the Market
2. Folder with unzipped JBoss EAP - I tried with jboss-eap-6.2.0.zip, jboss-eap-6.3.0.Beta.zip and also install with jboss-eap-6.2.0-installer.jar
3. Added "JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 6.1+ Runtime" to Eclipse -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Enviroments, connected to the mentioned folder and to JDK 7
4. At this point "JBoss EAP 6.1+ Runtime Server" is shown in View -> Servers and I can start it
5. Making new Java Project or Dynamic Web Project
6. In Project properties:

   - Targeted Runtime - "JBoss EAP 6.1+ Runtime" is checked
   - Project Facets -> Runtimes - "JBoss EAP 6.1+ Runtime" is checked

Then I go to Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Library -> Server Runtime - and the list there is empty.

The same problem with JBoss 7.1 Runtime, which I added through download from Eclipse. Empty "Server Runtime" list again.

How to fix this?

I tried a similar procedure with Apache Tomcat 7 and it is OK. But no success with JBoss.

EDIT: here can be something relevant https://community.jboss.org/message/811070
They write about "Default Classpath Entries", I don't have such caption in Server -> Runtime Enviroments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved with the last (currently) Eclipse - Luna Service Release 1 (Eclipse 4.4.1) - and JBoss Tools 4.2 for it.

Answer (score 0):

I can’t speak as to how/why/when it was created, but look in the hidden folders inside your project. A file by the name of ‘org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml” exists and isn’t understood by MyEclipse. Delete it and the error should go away. Mine did.

Answer (score 0):

i think this error because of some missing jar like jboss client jar. in your project. so try to add this jar in you project.

```
Right click on java project -> build path -> configure build path ->
 libreries -> add external jars or add jars -> browse jboss client jar -> applay -> ok.
```

it was working for me.

Comment: It was two years ago and the problem was solved for me with the next Eclipse release, as I noted. Thanks anyway!